# how to retrieve the value as array from a dynamically created textbox using its ID in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to this programming method. The case is I have created the checkbox and textbox dynamically where the name of the text box and check box is equal and it is handled using database.

The data I need to get is from the textbox which is selected using checkbox by the user.

The details in the array need to be name of the textbox and the value of the textbox

I created the checkbox and textbox using this method. Some thing like this

```
  Dim checkBox = new CheckBox()
  Form1.Controls.Add(checkBox)
  checkBox.Location = New Point(offset, 10)
  checkBox.Text = cur
  checkBox.Checked = True
  checkBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
```

I successfully created checkbox at run time. Help me getting the value, and suggest me with the suitable array list.

the naming for the check box is number 1 to n values same for the textbox

Comment: You already have a reference to the CheckBox in the variable `checkBox`. If you make the [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) of the variable wide enough, you will be able to access it where needed. Also, `checkBox` is rather a bad name for it as it clashes with the `CheckBox` type - almost any other name will make it much easier to work with.

Comment: Actually naming to the checkbox is not the problem the naming is 1 to n value and same to the textbox value where I ask for the method for getting that value in the array .. hop you understand now sir..          now i edited the question please refer to it

Comment: You can get the `.Text` from the CheckBox `checkBox` with `checkBox.Text`, similarly for any other property.

Comment: sorry sir i think you are not understanding my question ... actually getting the 'values' in the 'array' the index should be name of the 'textbox' and the respective index 'value' should be the value of the 'textbox' but in the same time the 'checkbox' should be 'checked'.in this how can solve ... sorry again if I made any mistake.in the original question.